# Can you prune blockchain without redownloading?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, pruning

I've downloaded the whole blockchain now I want to run a pruned node on another device. But if I klick on prune block storage in bitcoin core, it tells me that reverting this setting requres re-downloadin the entire blockchain. Is it possible to prune a copy of the blockchain I've already downloaded and if so how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Pruning doesn't require downloading again. It's if you'd want to go *back* to unpruned state that it needs to download things again (obviously, because the data isn't there anymore).

Comment: Ok but then how do I do that? As mentioned I can't figure out how to do it in the bitcoin core GUI. Is there a command for bitcoind that I need to use?

Comment: That sounds like you're already pruned, and you're trying to revert to unpruned state. Going from unpruned to pruned should just work.

Comment: No it wasn't. Turns out the warning I got in the GUI was misleading. Upon restart it didn't re-download but just pruned the blockchain I had already stored. Thx for your time!